# convert to json format

Tags: json, typescript

I have a method that iterates the values of a formulej, i display it in the console as key value

```
Object.entries(this.parameterForms[index].value).forEach(([key, value]) => {
     console.log(key + " : " + value);
});
```

the display in console:

```
TypeOfConvention : AL
cardBeneficiary : false
csr : aab
cardFamilly : true
```

I want to change the displaying format to json as below

```
{
  "TypeOfConvention": "AL",
  "cardBeneficiary": false,
  "csr": "123",
  "cardFamilly": true
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask]

Comment: What you have posted is not a valid json. It is js object literal. Do you actually want to construct an object or only change the output in console?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `console.log` each line, you should put the data into an object,

```
newObject[key] = value;
```

and after that:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(newObject, undefined, 2))
```